# Is it possible to hide the (All) Level for Attribute Hierarchies in SSAS Tabular model

Tags: ssas, dax, cube, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

In SSAS multidimensional model the (All) level is an optional level of hierarchy and it is a system-generated level. It contains only one member whose value is the aggregation of the values of all members in the immediately subordinate level. It is possible to show/hide this level by setting TRUE/FALSE for"**IsAggregatable**" property of attribute.

- [Database Dimensions - Configure the (All) Level for Attribute Hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/database-dimensions-configure-the-all-level-for-attribute-hierarchies?view=sql-server-2017)

My question is it possible to do the same in SSAS Tabular model (in Azure).

I can't find the corresponding property for this in my tabular model. Perhaps it is called something else or moved to another place. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found that this option not available in Azure Tabular model.
There is a link to [MS Azure Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32902774-default-members-on-analysis-services-tabular-model) and as I can see this issue still open.

The same unswer I got on [MSDN SSAS Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7f53630-30a5-44b8-a898-9bc5a02efa8e/how-to-hide-the-all-level-for-attribute-hierarchies-in-ssas-tabular-model?forum=sqlanalysisservices)

I hope it will save time to someone.